# Cannot maximize browser in Protractor

Tags: firefox, protractor

I'm kind of new to Protractor. I need to maximize my browser window using protractor.
 I tried `driver.manage().window().maximize();` because it is working in Selenium.

But, not working. Can someone help me with that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code to adjust browser window size.

```
//Maximize browser window

var width = 1800;
var height = 1500;
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Is there a method call maximize?

Comment: No. This si the only way to maximize the browser as far as I know. :)

Comment: Okay. What I need is to maximize the browser. Anyway, thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 8):

There is `maximize()`:

```
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

---

Note that to make it work on Mac+Chrome I had to set the dimensions manually first and then maximize:

```
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1400, 900);
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

Comment: I think this must be the accepted answer. I didn't actually know this. Thanks. This helped me too. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. From one day suddenly window().maximize() doens't work and all my tests time out. Changing window().maximize() to window().setSize() didn't work neither.

All I did to solve this problem was simply update protractor version from 4.0.4 to 5.1.1, then it works